# Which word does "evidence" refer to in this paragraph?

Tags: interpretation

Page 79 of [Mokard 2.2 (A smart card) security target](https://www.commoncriteriaportal.org/files/epfiles/0251b.pdf) :

> The TSF shall be able to relate the *identity* of the originator of the information,  and  the  application  package *contained  in  the* information  to  which  the  evidence applies.

I want to know what is the reference of the word "evidence" in the above sentences?

In the other words, which one is correct:

1. evidence applies to information, or
2. evidence applies to the application package that contained in the information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that *evidence* is related to the *evidence of origin* from the preceding point.

The entire section is called "Enforced proof of origin".

[image: Screenshot of PDF linked in Question]

Comment: And what is the origin? the Application Package?

Comment: The origin is the origin... "the point or place where something begins, arises, or is derived." It's a safety measure to make sure that all requests come from legitimate sources, I guess... or to at least track where the request comes from, in the case it's not legitimate.

Comment: excuse me, in the same sentences : _application package contained in the information_ : the information are in the application package or the application package is inside the information?